# SOLR mysql - Sorry, no dataimport-handler defined

Tags: mysql, solr, debian

I am trying to configure SOLR on Debian with mysql import.

Solr is running and I can visit admin area on http://localhost:8983/solr/ however I am unable to dataimport under my selected core - it reports **"Sorry, no dataimport-handler defined!"**

It doesn't report any errors (I get reverse dns lookup warnings since running on test machine) and **I was able to successfully import mysql via api** following this guide http://solr.pl/en/2010/10/11/data-import-handler-%E2%80%93-how-to-import-data-from-sql-databases-part-1/

Any ideas would highly appreciated!

My config is as follows:

```
<dataConfig>
    <dataSource type="JdbcDataSource"
   driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
   url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/mydatabase?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull"
   user="root"
   password=""/>

 <document name='tests'>
    <entity name='posts'
        query='select * from blog_posts'>
    <field column="ID" name="id" />
    <field column="TITLE" name="title" />
    </entity>
 </document>

</dataConfig>
```

**schema.xml**
default chema with added:

```
<field name="id" type="string" indexed="true" required="true" stored="true" />
<field name="title" type="string" indexed="true" required="true" stored="true" />
```

**solrconfig.xml**
default config with added

```
<lib dir="${solr.install.dir:../../../..}/dist/" regex="solr-dataimporthandler-\d.*\.jar" />
<lib dir="${solr.install.dir:../../../..}/dist/" regex="solr-dataimporthandler-extras-\d.*\.jar" />
<lib dir="${solr.install.dir:../../../..}/contrib/" regex="mysql-connector-java-.*\.jar" />

<requestHandler name="/dataimport" class="org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandler">
<lst name="defaults">
<str name="config">/opt/solr-6.4.0/server/solr/gradim/conf/mysql-gradim.xml</str>
</lst>
</requestHandler>
```

Comment: Does the log say anything? Have you restarted Solr after changing in your solrconfig? Are you changing the correct solrconfig?

Comment: Yes, I double checked and everything seems to be fine with settings and solr logs. I also restarted several times ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a bug specifically in Solr 6.4, which will be fixed in Solr 6.4.1. The issue reference is [SOLR-10035](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-10035) and the comments contain a quick workaround you can apply immediately.

Comment: I had installed the 6.4.2, in this version also am finding the error - no-dataimport-handler-defined. I Checked the dataimport.js file but it has already 'QUERY', you can help with any other info.

Comment: If you are seeing it on 6.4.2, it is a different issue. Create a new question and provide your own configuration. Or join the Solr Users mailing lists if you think you will need a discussion around your configuration rather than a Question and Solution.

Comment: Thanks Alex for the info.

Comment: What if I found the same issue  for the solr 5.4.1 and the link in answer above doesn't work. Can anybody help me fix it.

Comment: The issue with 5.4.1 would not be the same as in this question. I would suggest double checking your configuration (that you have the relevant section) first and - if still an issue - asking for help on the Solr Users mailing list.